# Rename table columns by mapping them to other table's column values

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have 2 tables:

Table A:

```
Perspectiveid   ColumnOrder   UIDisplayName 
-------------------------------------------
   213              1           Alpha
   213              2           Beta
   213              3           Gamma
```

Table B: columns `Id, Col1, Col2, Col3`

I want the final result as in Table B as :

```
(`Id, Alpha, Beta, Gamma`)
```

i.e, `Col1` in `table B` corresponds to `ColumnOrder 1` in `table A` and should be renamed with the `UIDisplayName[Alpha]` of `ColumnOrder 1`

Comment: . . I don't fully understand.  Do you want to change the column *name*s in `B` or do you want to change the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pivot to convert row into columns. You may use this link for more info on pivot [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017)
For your query :-

```
 ; with cte as (
 select Perspectiveid,cast(ColumnOrder as varchar(max)) as ColumnOrder,UIDisplayName from tableA)
 select * into temptable from (
 select Perspectiveid,ColumnOrder,UIDisplayName from cte
 ) as d
 pivot (
 max(ColumnOrder) for UIDisplayName in ( [Alpha], [Beta], [Gamma] )
 ) as P
```

This will give you result as

make this as temptable

```
   Perspectiveid   | [Alpha] | [Beta]  | [Gamma]
       213             1          2        3
```

After that delete from `temptable`

```
   delete from temptable
```

Now insert data from `yourtable` to this `temptable` as

```
  insert into temptable ( Perspectiveid , [Alpha], [beta], [gamma] )
  select id, col1, col2, col3 from #tableb
```

After that drop your tableB then rename your temptable to tableB

```
  Drop table #tableB

  GO
  select * into #tableB from temptable


  GO

  Drop table temptable
```

OR

if you are want to change each column individually then try this

```
 select ' exec sp_rename ''tableb.col' + cast(columnorder as varchar(5)) + ''', ''' + UIDisplayName + ''', ''COLUMN'''  from tableA
```

this will give you the query to execute and change column name individually.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that. The issue with this is Table B already has data. I only want to rename its column and not make changes to its data.

Comment: insert into temptable ( Perspectiveid , [Alpha], [beta], [gamma] )
  select id, col1, col2, col3 from tableb  Running this query gives the following error- Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 104
Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint.

Comment: I would like to mention that table A and table B are temporary columns - #tableA, #tableB

Comment: @Liza: try option mention in OR, this will give the result in queries.

Comment: I executed the OR part - it yielded:  exec  sp_rename '#Temp2.col1', 'Alpha', 'COLUMN'
On executing it, I got the error - Msg 15248, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_rename, Line 247 [Batch Start Line 108]
Either the parameter "@objname" is ambiguous or the claimed "@objtype" (COLUMN) is wrong.

Comment: @Liza: updated by ans, actually your datatype of `columnorder` in `tableA` is different and `col1, col2, col3` in `tableB` is different, i guess it is `varchar`. Now updated my ans please check

Comment: The last part- sp_rename  'temptable', 'tableb' is failing with error: An invalid parameter or option was specified for procedure 'sys.sp_rename'. I think this is due to the fact that my tableB is, in fact, #tableB

Comment: @Liza: try first option....i have updated my code for creating temptable, rename tableb with your table.

Comment: ahh...it is your temporary table then I suggest use temptable instead of your #tempb table. kindly mention the same in your question.

Comment: @Liza: or you may directly delete your `#tableB` and recreate it using `temptable`. see my updated ans.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CURSOR` to execute a dynamic `sp_rename`.

```
DECLARE @ColumnOrder AS INTEGER
DECLARE @UIDisplayName AS VARCHAR(32)

DECLARE C_ColumnTitle CURSOR FOR
    SELECT Table_A.ColumnOrder,
        Table_A.UIDisplayName
    FROM Table_A

OPEN C_ColumnTitle
FETCH NEXT FROM C_ColumnTitle INTO @ColumnOrder, @UIDisplayName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    DECLARE @SQLString AS VARCHAR(MAX)
    SELECT @SQLString = 'EXECUTE sp_rename ''Table_B.Col' + CAST(@ColumnOrder AS VARCHAR(32)) + ''', ''' + @UIDisplayName + ''', ''COLUMN'';'

    EXEC(@SQLString)

    FETCH NEXT FROM C_ColumnTitle INTO @ColumnOrder, @UIDisplayName

END

CLOSE C_ColumnTitle
DEALLOCATE C_ColumnTitle
```

Comment: Thanks, but it gave an error- Msg 15248, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_rename, Line 247 [Batch Start Line 111]
Either the parameter "@objname" is ambiguous or the claimed "@objtype" (COLUMN) is wrong.

Comment: It tells you that the column name is wrong. I've used Table_B as table name and Col1, Col2, Col3, ColX as columns names. Modify the script according to your objects names.